# ¿Se puede crear una consulta WHERE con la columna como parámetro?

Tags: python, sqlite

Tengo una duda, si se puede crear una consulta SQLite donde WHERE tome el parámetro `WHERE ? LIKE ?`
Actualmente tengo esto y funciona bien.

```py
def SearchLike(self,filter):
    try:
        sQuery = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Fname LIKE ?"
        result = self.ExecuteReader(sQuery,('{}%'.format(filter),))
    except Exception as err:
        result = str(err)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

  obj = Student()
  result = obj.SearchLike('b')
  print(result)

[(3, 'Benjamin', 'P. Tubbs', 'Male', 43, '838-0555172', 'dpbenjamin15@yopmail.com', 'Morning',1)]
```

Esta es la función `ExecuteReader`:

```py
def ExecuteReader(self,sQuery,param=[]):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sQuery,(param))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
```

Pero quiero hacer esto (ya que no solo quiero buscar por `fname` si no por otros campos, pero al hacerlo así, me devuelve un arreglo vacío []):

```py
def SearchLike(self,column,filter):
  sQuery = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ? LIKE ?"
  result = self.ExecuteReader(sQuery,(column,'{}%'.format(filter),))

if __name__ == '__main__':

 obj = Student()
 result = obj.SearchLike('Lname','b')
 print(result)
```

Comment: No entiendo si tienes un problema Python o un problema SQL. El query es una cadena de texto que puedes formatear a gusto, asi que no parece ser un problema Python. Mejor aclara con ejemplos con datos de entrada y salida. Puedes editar tu pregunta para ello.

Answer (score 0):

Piensa que cuando usas WHERE, estás refiriéndote a una columna. No vas a llamar a una columna como "?" Por tanto, la respuesta es No.

Respecto al "LIKE", tiene que ir o precedido, o seguido o entre %

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE FName LIKE '%Pe';
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ser sincero siempre vi lioso pasar los parámetros al ejecutar la función `execute` y siempre prefiero formatear el string tal que parezca una sentencia SQL y luego pasársela a `execute`. Yo lo haría así:

```py
#no utilizo filter dado que es una función de python
def SearchLike(self,col,filtro):
  sQuery = f"SELECT * FROM Student WHERE {col} LIKE {filtro}"
  result = self.ExecuteReader(sQuery)

#quitamos el otro parámetro a la función
def ExecuteReader(self,sQuery):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sQuery)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de un poco de investigación, me decidí por crear un lista de diccionarios, y así buscar por su clave, pero haciendo una consulta general a la base de Datos.

```
def SelectAll(self):
    try:
        sQuery = "SELECT * FROM Student"
        result = self.ExecuteReader(sQuery)
    except Exception as err:
        result = str(err)
    return result
```

Hacemos una llamada a SelectAll, pero desde SerarchLike.

```
def SearchLike(self,key,value):
    # Get data from DB
    lstValues = self.SelectAll()

    dictionaryList = []
    for item in lstValues:
        # Create new Dictionary
        newDictionary = {'ID':str(item[0]),'Fname':item[1],
                'Lname':item[2],'Gender':item[3],
                'Age':item[4],'Phone':item[5],
                'Email':item[6],'StudyShift':item[7],
                'GroupID':str(item[8])}
        # Add the dictionary to the list
        dictionaryList.append(newDictionary)
    # Create new list auxiliar
    auxiliaryList = []

    try:
        for element in dictionaryList:
            if(element[key] == value):
                auxiliaryList.append(element)
    except:
        return
    return auxiliaryList
```

Así podemos hacer búsquedas.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

objStudent = Student()
result = objStudent.SearchLike('ID','3')
for element in result:
    print(element)

{'ID': '3', 'Fname': 'Benjamin', 'Lname': 'P. Tubbs', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': 43, 'Phone': '838-0555172', 'Email': 'dpbenjamin15@yopmail.com', 'StudyShift': 'Morning', 'GroupID': '1'}
```